# System.Data.DataTable to list of arrays

Tags: powershell

In order to post to Google Sheet, I need to convert the results of the DataTable to list of arrays, but I haven't managed to do that.

So this is the DataTable:

```
team_name   name
---------   ----
team_WebDev User1
team_WebDev User1
```

and I need to convert it to:

```
@(@("team_WebDev ", "User1"), @("team_WebDev ", "User1"))
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

If you need to convert `DataTable` rows to arrays, just loop through the `DataTable.Rows` and use `ItemArray` property:

```
# filtering datatable
$filteredRows = $dataTable | where {$_.team_name -eq "team_WebDev"} | Select-Object -Property @('team_name', 'name')
$arrayOfArrays = @()
foreach ($row in $filteredRows)
{   
    $arrayOfArrays += @(,$row.ItemArray)
}
```

Comment: Mikhail, your suggestion works, but it seems I need to deal with some other object type (not DataTable as I initially stated). I need to convert $teamData to Array. This is my $teamData.

$teamData = $tbl | Where-Object {$_.team_name -eq $line[0]} | Select-Object -Property @('team_name', 'name')

Comment: OK, I've converted the $teamData (type: Object[]) to DataTable with "| Out-DataTable" and it works now, but I'm wondering if there is a better solution - to convert the filtered result of DataTable to array.

Comment: You can apply filtering just before looping through rows. It doesn't change the loop.

Comment: How do I do that?